# How to check a json schema for specific values in a objects of a nested array?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have json files with images and each image has multiple versions. I want to validate the data for specific dimensions (versions).

Currently validation is successfull on below json, but it shouldn't: [not working schema, nested array with objects](https://jsonschema.dev/s/1Zg3M)

```
{
  "Images": [
    {
      "Versions": [
        {
          "imgProperties": "x"
        },
        {
          "imgProperties": "z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My schema is:

```
{
  "Images": {
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Versions": {
          "type": "array",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "contains": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "imgProperties": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "foo1|bar1"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "imgProperties"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "contains": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "imgProperties": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "foo2|bar2"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "imgProperties"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try the validation only on versions it works correctly: [working schema, non nested array with objects](https://jsonschema.dev/s/W5ZJU). So I suppose it has to do with nesting, but I can't see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON Schema is not complete. I assume the validator you are using treats your schema as empty. At least add the following to the root level:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Images": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Versions": {
            "type": "array",
            "allOf": [
              {
                "contains": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "imgProperties": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "pattern": "foo1|bar1"
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [ "imgProperties" ]
                }
              },
              {
                "contains": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "imgProperties": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "pattern": "foo2|bar2"
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [ "imgProperties" ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you are using `allOf` to check your array items with `contains`. This means all provided sub-schemas must be valid. As a consequence, your array needs at least two items to be valid and a compliant validator should report this correctly.

Comment: The schema definition at root level was indeed the problem here. Still wondering why other validations were working without defining the schema. Though glad this headache is over.

Comment: A JSON Schema defines an "open" model. In other words, an empty schema allows any data. This is sometimes confusing because the validation is successful, but nothing is actually checked.